# Adding an `IDENTITY` column to an existing delta table (Databricks)

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

How to add an identity column to an existing delta table.

```
ALTER TABLE tname ADD COLUMN id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apparently you can't add a generated column. [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html) syntax doesn't seem to allow that.

As a workaround create a table from scratch and copy data:

```
CREATE TABLE tname_ (
    <tname columns>,
    id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
);
INSERT INTO tname_ (<tname columns>) SELECT * FROM tname;
DROP TABLE tname;
ALTER TABLE tname_ RENAME TO tname;
```